# mccv - gam fit linear

Tags: r, mgcv

I'm trying to understand (and relate) how much curvature one can expect from fitting a GAM to that obtained from a non-parametric lowess.

Is the fact that the GAM fit is quite linear for the two groups in the below, simply because that's likely to be the best fit (or have I mis-specified something)? I have tried changing the basis splines to tp from cr and adjusting the number of knots - there isn't much difference.

The model fit is:

```
gam_mod_neut <- gam(count_neutrophil ~ group + s(time, bs = "cr", by = group), method = "REML", family = tw, data = count_wide)
```

[image: lowess]

[image: GAM]

Comment: How have you derived the span of the lowess smoothers? Have you optimized that (e.g., using cross-validation)? Did you take the distribution family into account somehow?

Comment: I just used 'geom_smooth(method = loess, se = FALSE)' in ggplot.

Comment: Well, there you have it. The loess span is chosen arbitrarily (but often sensible for illustrations). The degrees of freedom in the gam smoothers are estimated. You can of course set them manually and set them to any value you like. See the documentation. (I don't understand why you'd want to do that, though.)

Comment: Thank you but sorry, I'm kind of missing your point. Are you saying that the span chosen in the ggplot smoother is too narrow and hence it shows excessive 'wiggliness' whereas the gam smoother is a better representation of the flexible fit?

Comment: No, I'm saying that ggplot2 sets the loess span to a default value. It is not estimating the smoothness. mgcv estimates/optimizes the smoothness (based on your data). You can of course try to tune the estimation in mgcv but your loess plot is not useful as a reference for that (unless you want to switch off the estimation in mgcv). You could also estimate the smoothness of the loess fit (e.g., using cross-validation).

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used gams a lot (but can appreciate their flexibility) so my understanding is still somewhat rudimentary. What prompted me to post this was that a colleague was querying that the gam's aren't a good fit essentially because they're not curved enough. My thinking is that what is displayed is the best fit for the data even if the fit looks more linear than curved - I just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: Well, the other clear difference between the two fits is the distribution family in your GAM. That impacts the estimation of smoothness.